# Oracle SQL: Is ORDER BY non unique field deterministic?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Let's say I have a view `MYVIEW`

```
COL1[CARCHAR2]    SORTINGCOL[NUMBER]
"itm1"            100
"itm2"            101
"itm3"            100
```

and I query the following statement

```
SELECT *
FROM MYVIEW
ORDER BY SORTINGCOL;
```

Is it **guaranteed** (=can I rely on) that the returned order is always the same? let's say

1. `item1` (with a value of 100)
2. `item3` (with a value of 100)
3. `item2` (with a value of 101)

It's clear that `item2` will always end up being the last, but what about `item1` and `item3` with the same `SORTINGCOL` value?

Comment: SQL is a language where you tell the system *what you want* (rather than how to do it). One important aspect of this is, if you don't *ask* for something, then generally, the system is free to perform activities in any order it chooses to, so long as what it produces does match what you asked for. If the output order is important to you, make sure you provide enough information in `ORDER BY` to uniquely define the order.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No. SQL in general and Oracle in particular do not guarantee stable sorts.  That is, you can run the same query twice and get different ordering -- when the keys have ties.

This is because SQL tables (and result sets) represent *unordered* sets.  Hence, there is no "natural" ordering to fall back on.  In general, it is a good idea to include additional keys in the `order by` to make the sort stable.

EDIT:

I want to add one more thought.  Your example is for overall sorting in a query, where the issue is a bit abstract -- that is, any given run of the query is going to look correct.  It becomes a bigger issue with window functions.  So, it is possible that:

```
select v.*, row_number() over (order by sortingcol) as col1,
       row_number() over (order by sortingcol desc) as col2
from myview v
```

would yield inconsistent results.  Under normal circumstances, we would expect `col1 + col2` to be constant.  However, with ties, this is often not going to be the case.  This affects `row_number()` and `keep`.  It does not affect `rank()` or `dense_rank()` which handle ties consistently.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation!

Comment: In general the thesis "we would expect col1 + col2 to be constant" is wrong. For example: WITH cte (id, s) AS (
 SELECT generate_series(1, 10) AS id, FLOOR(random() * 2) AS s
) SELECT c1.id, c1.s, c2.id, c2.s, c1.id + c2.id AS value_should_be_constant
    FROM (SELECT cte.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s, id) rn FROM cte) c1
     INNER JOIN (SELECT cte.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s, id DESC) rn FROM cte) c2
         ON c1.rn = c2.rn